# Number of nodes in output later greater than number of classes in a neural network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, classification

While training a neural network, on the fashion mnist dataset, I decided to have a greater number of nodes in my output layer than the number of classes in the dataset.

The dataset has 10 classes, while I trained my network to have 15 nodes in the output layer. I also used a softmax.

 Now surprisingly, this gave me an accuracy of 97% which is quite good.

This leads me to the question, what do those extra 5 nodes even mean, and what do they do here?

 Why is my softmax able to work properly when the label range(0-9) isn't equal to the number of nodes(15)?

 And finally, in general, what does it mean to have more nodes in your output layer than the number of classes, in a classification task?

I understand the effects of having lesser nodes than the number of classes, and also that the rule of thumb is to use number of nodes = number of classes. Yet, I've never seen someone use a greater number of nodes, and I'd like to understand why/why not.

I'm attaching some code so that the results can be reproduced. This was done using Tensorflow 2.3

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(training_images, training_labels) ,  (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

training_images = training_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason you are able to use such a configuration is because you have specified your loss function as sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

let's understand the effects of greater output nodes in forward propagation.
Consider a neural network with 2 layers.
1st layer - 6 neurons (Hidden layer)
2nd layer - 4 neurons (output layer)

You have dataset X whose shape is(100*12) ie. 12 features and 100 rows.
you have labels y whose shape is (100,) containing two unique values 0 and 1.
Therefore essentially this is a binary classification problem but we will use 4 neurons in our output layer.

Consider each neuron as a logistic regression unit. Therefore each of your neurons will 12 weights (w1, w2,.....,w12)
Why? - Because you have 12 features.

Each neuron will output a single term given by a. I will give the computation of a in two steps.
z = w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ........ + w12*x12 + w0  # w0 is bias
a = activation(z)

Therefore, your 1st layer will output 6 values for each row in our dataset.
So now you have a feature matrix of 100 * 6.

This is passed to the 2nd layer and the same process repeats.

So in essence you are able to complete the forward propagation step even when you have more neurons than the actual classes.

Now let's see backpropagation.

For backpropagation to exist you must be able to calculate the loss_value.
we will take a small example:
y_true has two labels as in our problem and y_pred has 4 probability values since we have 4 units in our final layer.

```
y_true = [0, 1]
y_pred = [[0.03, 0.90, 0.02, 0.05], [0.15, 0.02, 0.8, 0.03]]
# Using 'auto'/'sum_over_batch_size' reduction type.
scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
scce(y_true, y_pred).numpy() # 3.7092905
```

How is it calculated:
( log(0.03) + log(0.02) ) / 2

So essentially we can compute the loss so we can also compute its gradients.

Therefore no problem in using backpropagation too.

Therefore our model can very well train and achieve 90 % accuracy.

So the final question,  what are these extra neurons representing. ie( neuron 2 and neuron 3).
Ans - They are representing the probability of the example being of class 2 and class 3 respectively. But since the labels contain no values of class 2 and class 3 they will have zero contribution in calculating the loss value.

Note- If you encode your y_label in one-hot-encoding and use categorical_crossentropy as your loss you will encounter an error.